# Matlab, I need to find the row with the smallest sum of its elements

Tags: matlab

```
  E = M;
fbest = inf;
for k = 1:Rows
    if sumsqr(E(k,1:Columns)) < fbest
        fbest = sumsqr(E(k, 1:Columns));
        xbest = E(k, 1:Columns);
    end
end
```

E is the matrix
i need to find which row has the smallest square root of its added values,
I the output gives me fbest= inf and nothing for xbest. I cant seem to see why it isnt working.

*Note*

I'm working in **Matlab 2019a**

Comment: [`sumsqr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/sumsqr.html) doesn't take **square root** of the added values. Rather it takes **square** of each element and then add the resultant elements. Please see the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorization and the `min` function.

```
E_sumsqr = sqrt(sum(E.^2, 2)) ; % determine square root of sum of squares per row
[min_value, min_index] = min(E_sumsqr) % get the minimum value and index of the row
E_minrow = E(min_index, :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
[val,idx] = min(sqrt(sum(E.^2,2)))
```